# java program won't output words

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a text to nato alphabet but I can't figure out what is the problem. I tried to split the text into characters and then put it in arrays then in a for loop to test if the character is equal and write the correct word

**Sample Text :** hello

**Result:** hotel echo lima lima oscar

[image]

```
package text2nato;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Text2nato {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the text to conver to nato :");
String text = scan.nextLine();
char[] carray = text.toCharArray();

for(int i=0;i<carray.length;i++){
if("a".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("alpha");
}if("b".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("brabo");
}if("c".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("charlie");
}
if("d".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("delta");
}if("e".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("echo");
} if("f".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("foxtrot");
}if("g".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("golf");
} if("h".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("hotel");
} if("i".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("india");
} if("j".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("juliet");
} if("k".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("kilo");
} if("l".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("lima");
} if("m".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("mike");
} if("n".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("november");
} if("o".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("oscar");
} if("p".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("papa");
} if("q".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("quebec");
} if("r".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("romeo");
} if("s".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("sierra");
} if("t".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("tango");
} if("u".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("uniform");
} if("v".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("victor");
} if("w".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("whiskey");
} if("x".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("x-ray");
} if("y".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("yankee");
} if("z".equals(carray[i])){
System.out.print("zulu");  
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: No `"string"` will ever be equal to a char. You should use `'a' == carray[i]` etc. Moreover, you should obviously refactor you code. It doesn't even look like code, but rather like a distorted JSON file. It's extremely redundant.

Comment: So, what output are you getting currently when you enter "hello"?

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but please use a map or something instead of this wall of if statements.

Comment: I don't understand the close vote. Code is there. Input is there. Expected output is there. The unexpected outcome is described clearly ("won't output words"). Don't see how that qualifies as no-mcve. Maybe as a trivial typo (repeated 26 times...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have already pointed out in the comments that you're comparing a string to a char, which will never be equal. By way of illustration, try the following program:

```
public class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean x = "b".equals('b');

    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

The result will be `false`. You could argue that this is a bit of a "gotcha" in Java, but that's a matter of opinion.

Also, if you have that many `if` statements in a row, it's a pretty good hint that something's probably gone wrong. At a minimum, a `switch` statement would be far easier to read:

```
package text2nato;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Text2nato {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the text to convert to nato: ");
    String text = scan.nextLine();

    // You might want to consider converting the whole string to lowercase to make this case-insensitive
    char[] carray = text.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0; i < carray.length; i++){
      if (i > 0)
      {
         // We need to prepend a space here
         System.out.print(" ");
      }
      switch (carray[i])
      {
        case 'a': System.out.print("alpha"); break;
        case 'b': System.out.print("bravo"); break;
        // The rest of your cases go here
        // Be sure to handle the case where the user enters something invalid
        default: System.out.print(carray[i] + " is not a valid lowercase letter"); break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, indenting the code properly, adding some extra whitespace, and using a `switch` statement makes this *much* easier to read.